# Guardar imagen de picturebox en bd access con C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access-2010, picturebox

Tengo una BD Access 2016 con una tabla que contiene un campo objeto OLE, en Visual Studio 2012 tengo un proyecto de WF donde tengo un formulario que contiene un `pictureBox` para adjuntar el logo. Tengo un boton insertar que llama a la sentencia hecha en el `TableAdapter`.

El asunto es que me esta dando problemas adjuntar esa imagen , no consigo hacerlo ni como imagen ni con la ruta, algun consejo??

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    try
    {
        int numero = Convert.ToInt32(cPEmpresaTextBox.Text);
        Bitmap BmpImage = new Bitmap(logotipoEmpresa2PictureBox.Image);
        MemoryStream Mystream = new MemoryStream();
        BmpImage.Save(Mystream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] ImagenBytes = Mystream.ToArray();
        tblEmpresaTableAdapter.InsertarEmpresa(nombreEmpresaTextBox.Text, cIFEmpresaTextBox.Text, direccionEmpresaTextBox.Text, numero, poblacionEmpresaTextBox.Text, provinciaEmpresaTextBox.Text, estadoEmpresaComboBox.Text, cuotaAsociacionComboBox.Text, emailEmpresaTextBox.Text, paginaWebEmpresaTextBox.Text,ImagenBytes);
        MessageBox.Show("Registro añadido");
        conexion.Close();
        tblEmpresaTableAdapter.Fill(basededatos1DataSet.tblEmpresa);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : "+ex);
    }
}
```

La consulta funciona, porque he conseguido guardar el registro en la bd pero luego no se que hacer para recuperar el logo en jpg y verlo bien en el `PictureBox`.

Tal vez algo en el evento `BackgroundImageChanged` del `PictureBox` que compruebe si es jpg y sino transformarla??

Comment: Pon el código que estás utilizando para intentar cargar la imagen sí te podrán decir dónde puede estar el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Si en la table empresas definida en el TableAdapter tienes el campo byte array que mapea con el campo de la imagen al realizar un `GetData()` obtendrias por el id la empresa y junto a esta el campo de imagen asociado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: el campo "image_stream" de la imagen seria tu campo foto.

Cuando tengas el byte array lo conviertes a Image para asignarlo al Picturebox

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

[C# Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)